# Customize clarity color scheme using Angular 4

Tags: vmware-clarity

I would like to be able to change the color schemes for my clarity application. Is there a recommended way to doing this? I saw there were a few issues about this, but I didn't see anyone talk about an actual way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm currently implementing a dark theme to complement the light theme currently shipped with clarity.

As part of generating both light and dark themes for clarity, I'm building a way for Clarity consumers to create their own themes by overriding appropriate `SCSS` variables for the components and then building the clarity-ui css in their projects instead of consuming it as packaged on `npm`.

I'm expecting to have the first version of the feature released before Thanksgiving. You can follow along and stay up to date [here](https://github.com/vmware/clarity/issues/968)

Comment: Very awesome. I am following it now. Do you know if there will be instructions on how to get it set up in current projects?

Comment: Hey Corey. I’m glad your are excited. Feedback will be greatly appreciated. I’m working on documentation this week as the team reviews the pull request. If you are curious, you can see a dark theme css build artifact applied to what we call the kitchen sink app here: http://clarity-ks-dark.surge.sh. I’ll show how I added it to the app so it got built as part of the vender.css.

Comment: No doubt. I’m using it in a project at work so I’m going to be digging into it.

Comment: Hey, just to followup. Clarity shipped with the dark theme last week. 
Check here for more info: https://vmware.github.io/clarity/documentation/themes

Comment: Thanks for remembering! I appreciate it.